# Sencha - HTML ASCII codes in selectfield options

Tags: javascript, forms, mobile, sencha-touch, ascii

I have the following `Ext.form.Select`:

```
{
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    label: 'Temperature',
    name: 'temperature',
    options: [
        {text: '< 32°F',  value: 'below_32'}
    ]
}
```

I don't know how to get the option label to display how I want.  If I leave it with the less-than and degree sign as shown, then Chrome displays a less-than sign, the number `32`, a little question-mark box for the degree sign, and `F`.

If I do `{text: '&lt; 32&deg;F',  value: 'below_32'}`, then Chrome displays `&lt; 32&deg;F` in the field, but then when you tap the field and the select menu shows up, `< 32°F` is displayed in the menu as desired.  I want `< 32°F` to show up in both the field (when you're not selecting a value from the menu), and in the menu when you tap the field.

Comment: I have done no research on this, hence not really an answer. Have you tried `'\x3c 32\xb0F'` as your string?

Comment: @Hemlock:  submit that as an answer, it worked!  Turns out I can just do a `<` and it shows up fine, but I needed the `\xb0` to get the degree symbol.  `< 32\xb0F`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried '\x3c 32\xb0F' as your string?

Comment: `< 32\xb0F` was sufficient, I didn't need the `\x3c` for the `<` to work.  Thanks!